# Meaning of song verse "...all your mystery Like you and me is history"

Tags: phrase-meaning

There is a Brad Paisley's song called [Somebody knows you now](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6iP-dZS5zWU). In the end of the song he sings:

> Well baby **all your mystery** 
>  **Like you and me is history** 
>  'Cause somebody
>   knows you now

When he says that her mistery and they (maybe their relationship) are history, does he mean it is in the past, and it's over? Is it an idiom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"XXX is history" is an idiom meaning that it is finished. When XXX is a person ("you are history") it usually means that the relationship is finished.

"You and me is history" is grammatically odd, and I would interpret as "'you and me' is history", i.e. "the thing called 'you and me' (our relationship) is history".

I don't think "All your mystery" is part of the same phrase.

Comment: Maybe *"like you and me"* works as an appositive.

Comment: Could be. Detailed grammatical analysis of lyrics is often time wasted.